# UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit in UIImageView does not work correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I try to fit an Image into my `UIImageView` which is called imgBack
I define my `UIImageView` in the header as `IBOutlet`

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *imgBack;
```

in my `viewDidLoad` function I set the contentMode like this:

```
imgBack.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

But after I load an image into imgBack like this:

```
imgBack.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: imagePath];
```

it does not scale to fit into the imageview

This is the picture I load into imgBack:
[image i try to load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv6il.png)

And this is how it looks like in the view: [image in UIImageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2r6c.png)

As you see, the image does not fit into the View.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`

Comment: try it with this as well. But then its just cropped too.

Comment: did you set the frame for imgBack?

Comment: No, since I created the UIImageView as an IBOutlet on my Storyboard i didnt set a frame. Is a frame not just needed if I create the UIImageView programmatically?

Comment: so, in the story board, select imageview and set contentmode in storyboard itself.

Comment: Oh yeah, i can select it in the storyboard too but its still the same problem. I removed all the code to fit the image into the imageview and select it via the storyboard. But its still the same :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If changing ImageView contentMode does not work for you, then you can try to resize the image to fit in Image View with help of following code

```
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: imagePath];
imgBack.image = [self resizeImage: originalImage imageSize: imgBack.size];
```

and add this code to your ViewController

```
-(UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image imageSize:(CGSize)size
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height)];
        UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        //here is the scaled image which has been changed to the size specified
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return newImage;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it looks like an ugly workaround for me. Is the original image overriten by a smaller one with this?

Comment: Nopes you get a separate UIImage from this method which you can use in your UIImageView.  Original Image is not changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the image to `UIImageView` first and then change the `content mode`

```
imgBack.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: imagePath];
imgBack.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
imgBack.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Property 'imageView' not found on object of type 'UIImageView *'; did you mean 'maskView'?

Answer (score -2):

```
below are the mode try and check
UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
    UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,      // contents scaled to fit with fixed aspect. remainder is transparent
    UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,     // contents scaled to fill with fixed aspect. some portion of content may be clipped.
    UIViewContentModeRedraw,              // redraw on bounds change (calls -setNeedsDisplay)
    UIViewContentModeCenter,              // contents remain same size. positioned adjusted.
    UIViewContentModeTop,
    UIViewContentModeBottom,
    UIViewContentModeLeft,
    UIViewContentModeRight,
    UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
    UIViewContentModeTopRight,
    UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
    UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
```

Comment: I have tried the most of them but none works as it should. I think the one that should work is AspectFit